# Img src argument in function. not displaying image

Tags: javascript

I have searched for a solution to this problem but couldn't find anything specific. I am writing a javascript memory card game using a deck of cards thats i have individual images for. In the html table thats printed I have an img with an onlick event that calls my selectCard() function. this function takes the argument (img id) and uses that id to change the img src from back.gif to the corresponding front card (as stored in an array called preloadImages)

My problem is that when this happens the image src becomes [object%20HTMLImageElement].png instead of 0.png or 23.png or whichever card was clicked.

Can someone please help? Codeblock below

```
//sets up the table for the game
function setGame(){
            document.getElementById("gameArea").innerHTML = "";
            var newTable = "<table border ='1' align='center'><tr>";
                for(i=0; i<4; i++){
                        newTable +="<tr>";
                        for(j=0; j<13; j++){
                                var cardId = j+i*13;
                                newTable += "<td><img id = "+cardId+" src='back.gif' width='100' height='140' onclick='selectCard("+cardId+")'/></td>";
                                }
                                newTable += "</tr>";
                }
                newTable += "</table>";
            document.getElementById("gameArea").innerHTML = newTable;
            }

//selectCard Function
function selectCard(Id){
            var imageRef = document.getElementById(Id);
            if (imageRef.src.match("back.gif")) {
                    imageRef.src = preloadImages[imageRef]+'.png';
                    }
                    else {
                        imageRef.src = "back.gif";
                    }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure `[object%20HTMLImageElement]` is an HTML element, not the ID of an image. If I understand what you are trying to do correctly, you are taking the ID of the image and adding the extension ".png" to the end of it before setting the `src` of the image to that value. Whatever you are doing in your code is changing the `src` of imageRef to imageRef itself, not it's ID. Try this:

```
function selectCard(Id){
    var imageRef = document.getElementById(Id);
    if (imageRef.src == "back.gif") {
        imageRef.src = Id + ".png";
    } else {
        imageRef.src = "back.gif";
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I tried originally, it also doesn't work. I have an array with the images preloaded and would like to pull them from there if possible.

Comment: Oh, I see. You still need to get the ID/classname from the array. Try Sting's answer

Comment: This solution works if we use
if (imageRef.src.match("back.gif")) {

however it's still not pulling the image from the preloadImages array. but it's workable. Thanks!

Comment: do you want me to update my answer to `imageRef.src.match("back.gif")`?

Comment: I'd still like to see if someone has a solution that allows me to use the preloadImages array for the img id valiue. I also have a function that shuffles the cards when the game starts and that calls the preloadImages array in order to shuffle. so while this solution works it will only work on a sorted cardset.

Comment: can you post your HTML so I can have a better understanding of what you are trying to do?

Comment: I could post the whole program but it's a bit lengthy. let me know if thats more useful.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by using the following code line

```
imageRef.src = preloadImages[Id].src;
```